# Processing ProcessParameters as XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

I am trying to extract values from an XML column. Unfortunately, whatever combination I try, I can't get any meaningfull result out of it.

A test script with data can be found [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/73392)

**Related questions that did not turn the light on for me**

- [Getting values from XML type field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558400/getting-values-from-xml-type-field-using-in-sql-server)
- [XML query() works, value() requires singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302064/sql-server-2005-xml-query-works-value-requires-singleton-found-xdtuntyp?rq=1)
- [Getting rowsets from XQuery and SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652268/getting-rowsets-from-xquery-and-sql-server-2005?rq=1)

**Example of the contents of one item**

```
<Dictionary xmlns="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:mtbwa="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
  <mtbwa:BuildSettings x:Key="BuildSettings" ProjectsToBuild="$/Projects/BpABA/Dev/V6/DUnit/FrameworkTests.dproj">
    <mtbwa:BuildSettings.PlatformConfigurations>
      <mtbwa:PlatformConfigurationList Capacity="1">
        <mtbwa:PlatformConfiguration Configuration="Debug" Platform="Win32" />
      </mtbwa:PlatformConfigurationList>
    </mtbwa:BuildSettings.PlatformConfigurations>
  </mtbwa:BuildSettings>
  <mtbwa:SourceAndSymbolServerSettings SymbolStorePath="{x:Null}" x:Key="SourceAndSymbolServerSettings" />
  <mtbwa:AgentSettings x:Key="AgentSettings" MaxExecutionTime="01:00:00" MaxWaitTime="04:00:00" Tags="Delphi 5" />
  <x:Boolean x:Key="CreateWorkItem">False</x:Boolean>
  <x:Boolean x:Key="PerformTestImpactAnalysis">False</x:Boolean>
</Dictionary>
```

**Latest attempt**

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' AS mtbwa)
, q AS (
  SELECT  CAST(bd.ProcessParameters AS XML) p
  FROM    dbo.tbl_BuildDefinition bd     
) 
SELECT  X.Doc.value('mtbwa:BuildSettings[0]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS 'Test'
FROM    q CROSS APPLY p.nodes('/mtbwa:Dictionary') AS X(Doc)
```

**Background**

The column `ProcessParameters` is part of the TFS build system in the `tbl_BuildDefinition` table.
The complete DDL is as follows

```
USE [Tfs_ProjectCollection]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tbl_BuildDefinition]    Script Date: 06/19/2012 16:28:56 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_BuildDefinition](
    [DefinitionId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GroupId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DefinitionName] [nvarchar](260) NOT NULL,
    [ControllerId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DropLocation] [nvarchar](260) NULL,
    [ContinuousIntegrationType] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [ContinuousIntegrationQuietPeriod] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LastBuildUri] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [LastGoodBuildUri] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [LastGoodBuildLabel] [nvarchar](326) NULL,
    [Enabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](2048) NULL,
    [LastSystemQueueId] [int] NULL,
    [LastSystemBuildStartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [ProcessTemplateId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProcessParameters] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ScheduleJobId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_BuildDefinition] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GroupId] ASC,
    [DefinitionName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_BuildDefinition] ADD  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [ScheduleJobId]
GO
```

Comment: You're most certainly not - at least not from what I've seen so far from you on this site :-) :-) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a wrong namespace defined for your `mbtwa` prefix in your XML/XQuery text, and you need to use 1-based indexing to get at the data when using the `.value()` function (not 0-based like commonly used).

So try this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow' AS mtbwa, 
                    DEFAULT 'clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib')
, q AS (
  SELECT CAST(bd.ProcessParameters AS XML) p
  FROM dbo.tbl_BuildDefinition bd     
  WHERE DefinitionId = 1
) 
SELECT  
    X.Doc.query('mtbwa:BuildSettings') AS 'Node',
    X.Doc.value('(mtbwa:BuildSettings/@ProjectsToBuild)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS 'ProjectsToBuild'
FROM
    q 
CROSS APPLY 
    p.nodes('/Dictionary') AS X(Doc)
```

This should give you the whole `<mtbwa:BuildSettings>` node as XML (using the `.query()` function), as well as the value of the single attribute `ProjectsToBuild` (`$/Projects/BpABA/Dev/V6/DUnit/FrameworkTests.dproj`) of that node.

[image]

If you want a whole node (as XML), then you need to use `.query('xpath')` - the `.value()` function can get you the inner text of a node (if present), or the value of a single attribute.

Does that help at all?

Comment: I have altered your statement to fit into my actual query but it is not returning any results. In case you've missed it in my question, I have setup a testbed [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/73408/81549/processing-processparameters-as-xml-in-sql-server) where I have incorporated your statement.

Comment: OK, what if you tackle just the XML (leave out your other table) ? Does that return values? It does for me....

Comment: You should be able to copy/paste the entire statement and run it?!

Comment: I have to go (again) for an hour. Don't mistake my absence for lack of interest... *"I will be back"*

Comment: @Lieven: OK, I took your table definition and inserted that sample XML into it - adapted my query. I can definitely retrieve *something* from that XML using my XQuery